# Replicate Excel Function LARGE() in SQL

Tags: sql-server, function

Excel Function [LARGE(Array, K)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/large-function-3af0af19-1190-42bb-bb8b-01672ec00a64) returns "the k-th largest value in a data set (array)". This pseudo code would return the largest value in the array:

```
= LARGE([Mw01]:[Mw07], 1)
```

While this pseudo code return the 3rd largest in the array

```
= LARGE([Mw01]:[Mw07], 3)
```

Testing the function, I imagine the code behind the function sorts the array and assigns a rank to each element, then returns the element that matches parameter "k". That allows the function to return a value where "K" can range from 1 to the total number of elements in the array.

I've mocked up the example picture provided on the Microsoft site to show how values in their example can be returned based on "K" :

[image]

Note by my changes, both of the below formulas will return 5 even though the represent the same value:

```
=LARGE(A2:B6,3)
=LARGE(A2:B6,4)
```

Replicating a result in SQL when "K=1" is fairly easy to implement:

```
[MAXMW7] = (select max(MW) from (values ([X].[Mw01]),([X].[Mw02]),([X].[Mw03]),([X].[Mw05]),([X].[Mw06]),([X].[Mw07])) as X(MW))
```

My requirement is to find the 2nd highest value in a Monotonically Increasing list of MW values. Because I've already calculated the MAX value in the list, I can NULL out any other values that match that value. This solution works but is not ideal: it doesn't replicate the Excel function)

[image]

I think a better solution that more closely matches Excel functionality is to introduce MSSQL functions LEAD/LAG, which could involve pivoting column data into rows, but I'm having difficulty visualizing it.

Comment: So why tag Excel? Excel does not have an issue with large()...

Comment: @SolarMike : Thanks for the feedback - I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can create a Table-Valued Function that will parse the array and return the Nth largest.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1'
Declare @N int          = 3

Select Value
 From  (
        Select RN = row_number() over (order by try_convert(float,Value) desc)
              ,Value = try_convert(float,Value)
         From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape(@S,'json'),',','","')+'"]' )
       ) A
 Where RN=@N
```

**Results**

```
Value
7
```

Another option ... Just for fun

```
Declare @N int          = 3

Select Value
 From (
         Select Value
               ,RN = row_number() over (order by Value Desc)
          From  ( values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
                        ,(6),(7),(8),(9)
                ) n(Value)
      ) src
 Where RN = @N
```

Comment: And if the input array values are not unique, just replace `row_number()` with `dense_rank()`.

Comment: @RogerWolf  Excel's large() would return only one value even if there were dupes.

Comment: I mean, your current code will behave differently from Excel's spec on an array like this: `'9,9,7,9,5,4,3,2,1'`. Docs state that `Large()` will return 5, your code returns 9.

Comment: @RogerWolf  I see what you are saying now.

Comment: @RogerWolf: I presume though that John's "Just for fun" option, is still solid?

Comment: @BillRoberts Both will work.  To discount dupes, use dense_rank() instead of row_number()